# How do I create columns in a data frame based on a date range?

Tags: r

I have a date range:

```
start_date <- "2019-01-01"
end_date <- "2019-01-05"

range <- seq(as.Date(start_date), as.Date(end_date), by = 1)
```

And an empty data frame:

```
output <- data.frame()
```

How can I create new columns within the data frame based on the date range, with each column representing a day in the range?

The desired outcome is this (values are `0` for example purposes only):

```
   2018.01.01  2018.01.02  2018.01.03  2018.01.04  2018.01.05
1           0           0           0           0           0
2           0           0           0           0           0
3           0           0           0           0           0
4           0           0           0           0           0
5           0           0           0           0           0
```

I would have thought that something like this might have worked, but it doesn't:

```
for(i in range){
  output$i <- i
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is `replicate`

```
l1 <- length(range)
setNames(data.frame(replicate(l1, data.frame(col1 = rep(0, l1)))), range)
```

---

Or using `rep`

```
data.frame(setNames(rep(list(rep(0, l1)), l1), range), check.names = FALSE)
```

---

Or use the `matrix` route

```
as.data.frame( matrix(0, l1, l1, dimnames = list(NULL, 
           as.character(range))), check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  `replicate` works best for me (no `X`s present in column names).

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy. If you are using `data.frame` call at the end, specify `check.names = FALSE` as it will by default by `TRUE` and this looks into `make.names` which will not allow to have a column name starting with number, thus it adds `X`

Comment: Great, thank you - will do.  I have a further question - your examples specify `rep(0, 5)` but what if the date range is longer or shorter?  Is there a dynamic version of this, as such?  The date range won't always be five days.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy. It is just to replicate the number of rows as showed in the example.  Not related to range though.  You can change the `5` to any number and this would be the number of rows of the dataset

Comment: Yes, of course, you're absolutely right - I completely misread it (I see it now).